# Migrate the wordpress site to another domain on other server and getting error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, restore

Facing this error

[image]

I have a lot of woocommerce products on my wordepress site, and now I want to change my wordpress theme and redeveloped this. for this purpose I want to save my products on another domain and after development again restore it to it's original domain which is hafeezcenterlhr.com/

Comment: Updraft shows this page when the backup is still running in the background. Try waiting for it to finish. If that doesn't work out then delete the backup and re-create it. If that also doesn't work then use the "All in one WP migration" plugin. That is so far the best for the whole website backup. https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

Comment: Yes, Now Updraft Backup have completed and it's redirect to the main site, but I want to store this data on its subdomain

Comment: Here "Data" means full website right? Cause updraft takes a backup of the whole website and not just Woocommerce products. To restore this backup to a subdomain you can install WordPress on the subdomain and upload the updraft files to restore it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.